# JMS Message Persistence on ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I need to ensure redelivery of JMS messages when the consumer fails

The way the producer is set up now - DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory and Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE

I'm trying to build a jar and try in here to save the message into the server, once the app is able to consume, the producer in the jar will produce the message to the app.

Is that a good approach to do so?! any other way/recommendation to improve this?

```
public void handleMessagePersistence(final Object bean) {

     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     final String beanJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(bean); // I might need to convert to xml instead

    // parameterize location of persistence folder
    writeToDriver(beanJson);

    try {
        Producer.produceMessage(beanJson, beanJson, null, null, null);

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error producing message ");
    }
}
```

here what I have to writ out the meesage:

```
private void writeToDriver(String beanJson) {

    File filename = new File(JMS_LOCATION  + 
            LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")) + ".xml");

    try (final FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(filename)) {
        try (final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileOut)) {
            out.write(beanJson);
            out.flush();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to write out : " + beanJson, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The broker handles redelivery to the consumer automatically. You don't generally want the consumer and producer to coordinate redeliveries with each other-- it defeats the purpose of using the broker.

Comment: I found there's a kahaDB persistence now, that I Could use. not sure how it works yet.

Comment: kahadb is ActiveMQ's persistence storage.. data/kahadb/db-0.log.. etc . It stores the messages, subscription info and other stateful data